# Cannot connect to Excel SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm trying to create a data flow task which brings data from Excel File to SQL table. I'm doing it in SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 as an SSIS package. 
However, when I run the task I receive below error:

> [Excel Source [52]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

Would you be able help please?

Thank you

Complete Error message:

> SSIS package "C:\Users\adm.turpan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services
>   Project1\project.dtsx" starting. Information: 0x4004300A at Excel as
>   source, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning. Error:
>   0xC020801C at Excel as source, Excel Source [52]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed. Error: 0xC0047017 at Excel as
>   source, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Source failed validation and returned
>   error code 0xC020801C. Error: 0xC004700C at Excel as source,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation. Error:
>   0xC0024107 at Excel as source: There were errors during task
>   validation. SSIS package "C:\Users\adm.turpan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services
>   Project1\project.dtsx" finished: Success.

Comment: What are the other errors in the log? One of them contains the actual explanation. Most likely the file path is wrong

Comment: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Comment: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.

Comment: Is the file a real Excel file or a CSV/HTML file with an `.xls` extension? Can you open it with Excel?

Comment: Error: There were errors during task validation.

Comment: Can you open it with Excel? Where does the file come from?

Comment: It is real excel, I can open it.

Comment: Validation errors also appear in the log. They also appear on the source and connection manager in the dataflow design view

Comment: Those 4 are all the errors in the log. I've checked the path, it's correct.

Comment: There can be several reason for this error and only after looking at the complete error message we will know what's exactly wrong. For time being I would recommend you to try change run64BITRuntime as False and set Delay validation as True

Comment: Hi mehtat_90, I'm pasting above the complete error message.

Comment: Regarding run64BITRuntime as False - where can I find this setting? Cause I'm looking into project's properties, but cannot see anything like that.

Comment: I found it and it seems that solves my issue, although I'm getting different errors now. I'll try to solve them and let you know..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

mehtat_90 was right. you need to set run64BitRuntime to False. See below where to find it:

Project -> Properities ->
[image]

Comment: This fixes the error given; though I wonder why... what is it with 64 bit runtime that SSIS and Excel do not like? My best guess would be missing drivers... anyone?

Comment: @Mark The Excel provider is not available for 64 bits (or at least was)

Answer (score 1):

for whom, the above answers didn't work, also try this. Some times when the file is open, it creates a temp/hidden file in the same location and it is only visible to the one who opened it. So place a break point right before the load and check the value for "FileName" which is being passed. The temp/hidden files would be in thumb.db for excel and different for different file formats. Hope this helps for someone.

Answer (score -1):

- Right Click on Project name
- Select Properties
- Select configuration properties
- Select Debugging
- Select "False" in Run64bitRuntime.

Answer (score -2):

You should run sql job in 32 bit therefore you should select 32-bit runtime checkbox in the configuration of SSIS Job.

[http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html#:~:text=Right%20Click%20the%20SSIS%20project,and%20select%20false%20under%20Run64bitRuntime.&text=Edit%20your%20job%20and%20then,%22Use%2032%20bit%20runtime%22](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html#:%7E:text=Right%20Click%20the%20SSIS%20project,and%20select%20false%20under%20Run64bitRuntime.&text=Edit%20your%20job%20and%20then,%22Use%2032%20bit%20runtime%22)